# Restrict an application for some time Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dialog

I am implementing a function that restricts an application for 10 minutes when a user inputs incorrect codes more than 5 times. I have implemented for the timer not to be initialized when they restart the application. When they restart the application, they cannot click any button but can see a dialog for 10 minutes. It's okay to know which function to use or just explain me briefly.
All help will be greatly appreciated.

> **I have tried**

I stored the start time in `sharedPreference` and subtracted it from `System.currentTimeMillis`. So, when the result is more than 600000 (10min), they can finally start using the application.

> **My question**

1. I would like to know how to keep showing a dialog when the application is restarted in my code.

> My fragment

```
private lateinit var binding : FragmentHelpBinding
private lateinit var viewModel : HelpViewModel
private lateinit var mContext: MainActivity

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
super.onAttach(context)
mContext = context as MainActivity
}

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
 ): View? {
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_help, container, false)

return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HelpViewModel::class.java)
binding.viewModel = viewModel

otpTimeLimit()
}

private fun otpTimeLimit() = runBlocking {

val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
var startTime = currentTime
var pref: SharedPreferences? = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("otpTrialLimit", MODE_PRIVATE)
pref?.edit()?.putLong("startTime", startTime)
pref?.edit()?.commit()
          
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <600000) {
    // dialog will show up here and should last for 10 min 
    clickDialog()
}else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >=600000) {
    // and when 10 minutes passed, it should dismiss              
}
}


private fun clickDialog() {
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.help_dialog, null)
var alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
    .setView(view)
    .create()
val titleText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title_text_dialog)
val contentText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.content_text_dialog)

binding.btnGoSearch.setOnClickListener {
    titleText.text = getString(R.string.help_notification)
    contentText.text = getString(R.string.notification_content)
    alertDialog.show()
  }
}
```

Comment: So is this fragment showing the UI that will be usable after the dialog goes away? Or do you open some other dialog when it goes away? Right now it looks like your dialog doesn’t show until some button is pressed. I don’t see any code where you determine whether this lockout timer should be initiated. You’re immediately resetting the time to 10 minutes when this fragment is created, every time it’s created.

Comment: Is the dialog only supposed to show if the user presses the button, and if the times up the button does something else?

Comment: @Tenfour04 When the users click `btnGoSearch`, `var i` in viewModel will add up 1, and when it becomes 5, it moves to `VerifyOtpViewModel.Action.OtpTimeLimit`. Then, `otpTimeLimit()` will call the dialog. What I want to do is put a code in if clause of otpTimeLimit. I updated my codes and posted layout and viewModel code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 To be more clear about my code, 1) At the 5th trial, `else if(i == 5){
    _action.postValue(ConsumableValue(Action.OtpTimeLimit))`, in view Mode, will send value to `is VerifyOtpViewModel.Action.OtpTimeLimit ->` in Fragment. And here, it will call `otpTimeLimit()`. In `otpTimeLimit()`, I want to call otpTimeDialog() and set it to be shwon for 10 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one strategy for doing it. I assume you want this error state to persist even if the user closes and reopens the app, so the count and the time both need to be persisted.

The strategy here is to handle most of the logic in the view model to keep track of the state and persist it. In the Fragment, you only need to observer the live data: show the dialog if necessary during lockout state, and hide the dialog if it's open when the state transitions to not locked out.

ViewModel:

```
class HelpViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    companion object {
        private const val SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "HelpViewModelPrefs"
        private const val KEY_LOCKOUT_START_TIME = "lockoutStartTime"
        private const val KEY_ERROR_COUNT = "errorCount"
        private const val LOCKOUT_DURATION_MILLIS = 60_000L
    }

    private val sharedPrefs = application.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
        SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )
    private val _isErrorState = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isErrorState: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isErrorState

    // Set up this property so it automatically persists and is initialized
    // with any previously persisted value.
    private var errorCount: Int = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_ERROR_COUNT, 0)
        set(value) {
            field = value
            sharedPreferences.edit {
                putInt(KEY_ERROR_COUNT, value)
            }
        }

    init {
        // Figure out if we are already locked out and set state appropriately.
        // If we are locked out, schedule when to end locked out state.

        val lockoutStartTime = sharedPrefs.getLong(KEY_LOCKOUT_START_TIME, 0)
        val lockoutEndTime = lockoutStartTime + LOCKOUT_DURATION_MILLIS
        val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (now < lockoutEndTime) {
            isErrorState.value = true
            viewModelScope.launch {
                delay(lockoutEndTime - now)
                isErrorState.value = false
            }
        } else {
            isErrorState.value = false
        }
    }

    // call when the user performs an error
    fun incrementErrorCount() {
        errorCount++
        if (errorCount >= 5) {
            // Reset count, initiate lockout state, and schedule end of state
            errorCount = 0
            sharedPrefs.edit {
                putLong(KEY_LOCKOUT_START_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
            }
            isErrorState.value = true
            viewModelScope.launch {
                delay(LOCKOUT_DURATION_MILLIS)
                isErrorState.value = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the fragment, we handle the state by observing the live data. We keep a reference to any currently open dialog so we can automatically dismiss it if the state transitions while it is open. We null out references when the Fragment is destroyed so we don't leak them.

```
private var lockoutDialog: AlertDialog? = null
private val viewModel: HelpViewModel by viewModels()
private var shouldShowLockoutDialog = false

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    // ...

    viewModel.isErrorState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isErrorState ->
        shouldShowLockoutDialog = isErrorState
        if (!isErrorState) {
            lockoutDialog?.dismiss()
        }
    }

    binding.btnGoSearch.setOnClickListener {
        if (shouldShowLockoutDialog) {
            showLockoutDialog()
        } else {
            // TODO some behavior when not locked out
        }
    }
}

private fun showLockoutDialog() {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext())
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.help_dialog, null).apply {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_text_dialog).text = 
            requireContext.getString(R.string.help_notification)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content_text_dialog).text = 
            requireContext.getString(R.string.notification_content)
    }
    lockoutDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(
        requireContext(), 
        R.style.CustomAlertDialog
    )
        .setView(view)
        .setOnDismissListener { lockoutDialog = null }
        .create()
        .also { it.show() }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying this code and I have a few questions in `fun incrementErrorCount().` 1)`errorCount = 0` should be initialized later. 2) 3 lines down from `errorCount = 0`, `isErrorState.value = true` gives me an error that `Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread.` 3) It doesn't call the dialog function. How can I solve them?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what you're asking. 2) You must be calling this function from a background thread, but you cannot update livedata from a background thread. I don't know where you're calling it from. 3) I haven't tested this. You can use the debugger and step through the logic to figure out where there is unexpected behavior.